# Jquery Kendo Grid - Way to display duplicate rows when manually inserting rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a popup grid and when users add rows this will manually insert them going through the loop. Code below:

```
...
success: function (data) {
  if (data) {
    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
      schema: {
        model: {
          id: "ID",
          fields: {
            Data1: { required: false, editable: false },
            Data2: { required: false, editable: false }
          }
        },
        pageSize: 30
      });
      // This loop below manually inserts all the inputs
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        dataSource.insert(i, {
          ID: data[i].ID,
          Data1: data[i].RandomData1,
          Data2: data[i].RandomData2
        });
      } 
   }  
}
```

This works great. It inserts all the new rows and displays just fine. But the problem is, when users enter duplicate data, it will still take them and display.
I'm actually handling the duplicates in my stored procedure, so in the back end, it prevents from inserting the duplicates. But since the popup manually inserts, it just displays the duplicates. If I close out the popup grid, the main grid will be refreshed and the duplicates will be removed.

Is there a way to remove duplicates and display as one in the popup grid (maybe in the for loop.. some kind of validations to detect when there's same Data1 is entered then just display only 1)?

Comment: Inside the `for` loop put an `if` block and check if the data exists or not. By the way, I can't see all your code, but you're doing something wrong here. You're defining your datasource inside the success event of your Ajax post.

Comment: in the popup modal, there are textboxes and datepickers. Once you fill out information there and hit the submit button, if ajax call success then all that information will be populated in the grid. It's working great though.

Comment: just because it's working doesn't mean it's the right way of doing it. You don't have to redefine the datasource every time a record is inserted.

Comment: If I don't redefine when the ajax succeed, then it will throw an error saying the data source is not defined. What's your right way of doing it then? If you give me a link or suggestion then that could help me a little better.

Comment: I don't know. You need to show more code. How's your grid defined?

Comment: The example here should be clear enough:

https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-popup

Comment: In fact, if you define your grid correctly, with proper model and ID, then it won't allow duplicates. So, you won't have to do anything else in order to prevent that.

Comment: Go to your link and try adding the same product name, same unit price and etc. It will create duplicates. So that doesn't have proper model and id?

Comment: I think you still have to have a validation to prevent all that duplicate inputs even if your grid is defined with proper model, id and fields

Comment: Yes, it does, but as you can see in the code, the id is ProductID. Depending on what you need, you can define your ID, but that doesn't mean you should do that. You should only use the fields that are really ID (Primary Key) of your data. If not, you can just use a logic. Look at the API reference and find the right event for that.

Comment: you should use the `saveChanges` event: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/savechanges

Comment: I've been using it in my other apps. But this time I do not want users to click unnecessarily again to save that rows. That's why I'm trying to have one submit button and once its clicked then make an ajax call and if it passes then populate all that textbox inputs into a grid. I do not prefer to use that event as I'm not even using the kendo toolbar

Comment: You're doing it wrong. You can just disable the save button after submit.

Comment: What makes you think its just wrong? I mean I can enable the save button when the field input changes and disable when nothing changes. I just don't have a reason to have an extra button in the grid.

Comment: Again, if you don't provide code, nobody can help you.

Comment: That's really all about it in ajax success man. Below there's just exportExcel function.

Comment: Look at the link. It doesn't have anything to do with what you are doing. That's not all about it, by the way. Your question is about the Kendo Grid, but you are not even showing your grid.

Comment: I defined the grid exactly the same as the first link you provided. The only different thing is that I'm not using transport because I make ajax call to update

Comment: Then, why are you inserting the records that way?

Comment: Because instead of batch: true, I have to have textboxes and datetime pickers above the grid. And in the textboxes, actually textarea, users can have multiple inputs, comma separated. That's the requirement I'm working on. I have an empty grid below those textboxes and it only will be populated so that users can generate an excel spread sheet. When you close out that popup screen and go back, those textboxes and the grid are empty so that the users can do the same thing

Comment: Post your code. People won't be able to help you if you don't post your code. Good luck!

Comment: I just wanted to see if there's something I can add a validation in the loop. I don't really want anything. I will definitely try without re-defining the grid and see if it works.

Comment: I know in the for loop I should add if block and find the duplicates. I was just wondering if there was any Kendo source code, validations, etc I could refer to.

Comment: Thank you for your comments though.